# How to convert nested JSON files to CSV in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am completely new to python and trying to covert nested json files to csv. The current code I am trying to use is:

```
import json


def read_json(filename: str) -> dict:

    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
    except:
        raise Exception(f"Reading {filename} file encountered an error")

    return data


def normalize_json(data: dict) -> dict:

    new_data = dict()
    for key, value in data.items():
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            new_data[key] = value
        else:
            for k, v in value.items():
                new_data[key + "_" + k] = v

    return new_data


def generate_csv_data(data: dict) -> str:

    # Defining CSV columns in a list to maintain
    # the order
    csv_columns = data.keys()

    # Generate the first row of CSV
    csv_data = ",".join(csv_columns) + "\n"

    # Generate the single record present
    new_row = list()
    for col in csv_columns:
        new_row.append(str(data[col]))

    # Concatenate the record with the column information
    # in CSV format
    csv_data += ",".join(new_row) + "\n"

    return csv_data


def write_to_file(data: str, filepath: str) -> bool:

    try:
        with open(filepath, "w+") as f:
            f.write(data)
    except:
        raise Exception(f"Saving data to {filepath} encountered an error")


def main():
    # Read the JSON file as python dictionary
    data = read_json(filename="test2.json")

    # Normalize the nested python dict
    new_data = normalize_json(data=data)

    # Pretty print the new dict object
    print("New dict:", new_data)

    # Generate the desired CSV data
    csv_data = generate_csv_data(data=new_data)

    # Save the generated CSV data to a CSV file
    write_to_file(data=csv_data, filepath=data2.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works partly: I get a CSV file that contains all values. However, for the nested key fields it only gives me the "highest" level (e.g. I get "currentEmployments" but not "currentEmployments_firmId").

Could someone help me with this?

Sample json file:

```
{
  "basicInformation": {
    "individualId": 10000,
    "firstName": "Name",
    "middleName": "middleName.",
    "lastName": "lastName",
    "bcScope": "Active",
    "iaScope": "NotInScope",
    "daysInIndustryCalculatedDate": "1/1/2000"
  },
  "currentEmployments": [
    {
      "firmId": 001,
      "firmName": "firm1",
      "iaOnly": "N",
      "registrationBeginDate": "1/1/2005",
      "firmBCScope": "ACTIVE",
      "firmIAScope": "ACTIVE",
      "iaSECNumber": "10000",
      "iaSECNumberType": "100",
      "bdSECNumber": "1000",
      "branchOfficeLocations": [
        {
          "locatedAtFlag": "Y",
          "supervisedFromFlag": "N",
          "privateResidenceFlag": "N",
          "branchOfficeId": "10000",
          "street1": "street1",
          "city": "city",
          "state": "MD",
          "country": "United States",
          "zipCode": "10000"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "currentIAEmployments": [],
  "previousEmployments": [
    {
      "iaOnly": "N",
      "bdSECNumber": "20000",
      "firmId": 200,
      "firmName": "firm2",
      "street1": "street",
      "city": "city",
      "state": "MD",
      "country": "UNITED STATES",
      "zipCode": "10000",
    }
  ],
  "examsCount": {
    "stateExamCount": 0,
    "principalExamCount": 0,
    "productExamCount": 1
  },
}
```

Comment: Please post your Python code so we can see what you're doing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.